# ORACLE Shifting from from one version to another

Tags: oracle, linux, redhat

I have RHEL5 server with Oracle Home actual location is SAN, which is mounted on this server.

Now for few Reasons I have one more Server with RHEL 6 64Bit.

I will map those storage LUNS there.

What are the various ways to migrate and what are the advantages/disadvantages ?

Point 1: Take backup from old system and go for new install no new server ?

Point 2: Directly Map LUN and with few changes I can achieve this ?

Can I go for creating control files and copy and backup on new server and start making changes in spfile and pfile and go for changes ??

Comment: The installer will let you migrate your database to the new version "in-place". A backup should be taken nonetheless.

Comment: the same question is  posted by the same reader (and answered) four times http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64053/migration-of-oracle-database-from-rhel5-to-rhel6
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61343/move-complete-oracle-from-one-system-to-another
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61352/move-complete-oracle-from-one-system-to-another
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60020/oracle-shifting-from-from-one-version-to-another
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64053/migration-of-oracle-database-from-rhel5-to-rhel6

Answer (score 1):

Since you upgrade your OS, at some point you need to relink your Oracle software. In that case, easiest is to make a new software installation on the new server. Unmount the luns where the database is located from the old server and mount that on the new server where the database files should be mounted on the same locations as on the old server.

I hope that the ORACLE_HOME is not on the same lun[s] as where the database is located. If ORACLE_HOME does exist on the same LUN[s], make sure to create the new ORACLE_HOME on a different PATH and make sure that config files like /etc/oratab and listener.ora reflect this change.

This should give the quickest migration.
If there is to be done more than just re-mount the LUN[s], make sure to have a capable DBA involved. That will save you a lot of downtime and problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a production system or can you tolerate downtime? If it's the latter, the simplest solution would be to create a new 64-bit Oracle home for your new target environment and then use Data Pump to do an export and import.

For a production environment where you need to cut-over seamlessly to the new infrastructure , then Data Guard may be a good option. If you're running Oracle 11.2, you can have a heteregenous configuration with a 32-bit primary database and a 64-bit physical standby (see MOS 413484.1). You would then perform a simple switchover to quickly cut-over to your new 64-bit environment with minimal downtime.

Comment: Actually FULL ORACLE is ON SAN (storage). I want to Same  Mount The SAN LUN to new Server and set up environment for ORACLE and startup same INSTANCE on new Machine