# Move Complete ORACLE from one system to another

Tags: oracle, linux

[image]

I have 2 identical server with exact disk partitions (OS CENTOS 6.4 both ) [My college central oracle server].

Entire ORACLE HOME ( bin , control files, data files everything on oracle) is on 2nd Disk (which is not a OS disk)

Since OLD server had reached end of life (from HP) a new HP machine with upgraded RAM (OLD system had 16 GIG where as new system as 64 GIG).

Now Since All oracle Dependencies (RPM, libraries, environmental variables, JAVA, Users and groups) are already made on new server.

So Now Question is ..

Can I remove Disk [Oracle HDD] from OLD server and insert it on NEW server and just start Oracle (sqlplus "/ as sysdba" or dbstart and lnsctrl).

Can it will give any challenge.
(I have cold backups, export backup, & RMAN backup too).

I just want to give a try on above case.

Will this work ??

Comment: This will work if you prepared everything. oracle user and oinstall and dba group IDs are the same on both servers?

Comment: Yess everything is same. OS version , OS users, SID, ORACLE BASE, ORACLE HOME, Limits.conf, systcl.conf, exactly same

Comment: really amazing question .... expect a SA & a dba to be involved, if the data is of any interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Check OS users and groups: oracle, oinstall, dba.
- Check the contents of /etc/oratab and /etc/oraInst.loc files to verify if they point to an expected location.
- Check if these files are placed under the same paths:

  - init.ora, orapwd and similar
  - listener.ora, tnsnames and similar
  - control files
  - data files
  - redo log files
  - Oracle scripts such as oraenv (optionally - only if you use them), which are often placed in /usr/local/bin
- Check if you retain the same IP.
- Check if you retain the same DNS name.

And that's it, you are good to go.

Comment: Wonderfull!! Even I am thinking of same.. I will give a try this weekend & share results and accept your answer too

Comment: It worked.. Kept.. users hostname.. dns.. path.. OS version everything same.. It worked really

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will work if you have adapted all configuration information outside your oracle disk. I did it often on Sparc Solaris machines and it worked. This is more a Linux/Unix question: When can I copy  my software installation to a different server and must not install it. I did not know. So I think the better way is to **relink the Oracle binaries after you plugged in the disk into the new server**.  This is described in the [Oracle Database Administrator's Reference11g Release 2 (11.2) for Linux and UNIX-Based Operating Systems](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/cnfg_prd.htm#UNXAR154). Oracle suggested to relink the binaries whenever the operating system is patched or upgraded. Your new server is not 100% the same as your old server so relinking makes sense.
Simply set your Oracle environment in a terminal window of the new server and type `relink`. If you fall back to the old server do the same on the old server.

You can even copy oracle software to a new server and adapt it to the new environment (new hostname, new pathes and so on). This process is called 'cloning'. You can use a perl script. This is decribed in the [Oracle Database Installation Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2) for Linux](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/app_cloning.htm#LADBI1362) or you can use the Oracle Installer as described in the [Oracle  Universal Installer and OPatch User's Guide11g Release 2 (11.2) for Windows and UNIX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/em.112/e12255/oui6_cloning.htm#OUICG294).

Comment: 1Up for your answer.. I carried out this. Luckily I had Volumme Groups on the Physical disk.. so  'vgchange -an vg01' 'vgexport vg01'.. on new server imported the VG on same path and started Sqlplus.. & It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate your database with RMAN

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2.php

Comment: I already know RMAN/COLD/Export backups.. But I dont want to use that in this case..  I am checking if the oracle on OLD machine can be portable to new machine without any oracle installation on new machine