# Migration of oracle database from rhel5 to rhel6

Tags: oracle

I currently have oracle 11G running on RHEL5 on one server. (This Server has reached END of Life and no hardware support for it)

This server is connected with a Storage and ORACLE_HOME is on storage.

So Now I've a brand new machine with RHEL6 & I want to migrate that full oracle database to this machine.

So what is best feasible way.

I am thinking of RMAN backup and restore it on this new machine.  <-- This works

But If I connect that storage to new RHEL server what is best way (may be using control files or changes in Pfile or SPFILE can help) (then its just mapping of LUN task and connect to default oracle DB instance)

I don't want full procedure, just few ideas from SO users who faced this scenario and can share their best solution.

Comment: the same question was posed by the same reader (and answered)  already three times http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61343/move-complete-oracle-from-one-system-to-another
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61352/move-complete-oracle-from-one-system-to-another
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64053/migration-of-oracle-database-from-rhel5-to-rhel6

Comment: You might use export and import. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database[s] and software are on SAN/NAS storage. In that case you can remount them on the new server with the same path's. Because the OS version is different issue a relink for the Oracle binaries. Don't forget to also copy /etc/oratab, /etc/oracle and /usr/local/bin files etc.

Backup and restore are not bad at all but assuming there is some pre production environment with similar setup, you can use that to verify the procedure before the production migration. This is the quickest option (remounting).